# Xamarin SocketIO PCL Token

Tags: c#, xamarin, socket.io

I am trying to make a socket connection and pass the token in the headers of the connection. I keep getting a

"Error initializing handshake with https://webpage:8080/"

The code I have is:

```
NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
headers.Add("token", "xxxtoken");
client = new Client("https://supersecurepage:8080", headers);
client.Connect();
```

What could be wrong? Thank you!

The version of my nugget is: 1.0.2
And the SocketIO server is: 1.3.7

Thank you,

Michael Matias

Comment: is your "supersecure" page hosted locally or using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: it's in a public domain, I tried replacing that with it's IP address too.

Comment: But does it use a self signed certificate?

Comment: It is not self signed.

Comment: checl this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792240/socketio4net-error-initializing-handshake-with-https-localhost (even if your certificate is not self-sigend it may not be configured correctly) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219763/socketio4net-handshake-error